Why are constants considered as nullary operations?
On page 16 of Axiomatic Set Theory by Patrick Suppes, he states:

Individual constants may in fact be treated as operation symbols of degree zero.

Then I came across the following  definition of an n-ary operation.

Algebraic operation
n
-ary operation, on a set A


A mapping ω:An→A
of the n
-th Cartesian power of the set A
into the set A
itself. The number n
is known as the arity of the algebraic operation. Historically, the concepts of binary (n=2)
and unary (n=1
) operations were the first to be considered. Nullary (n=0)
operations are fixed elements of the set A
; they are also known as distinguished elements or constants. In the 20th century the concept of an infinitary operation appeared, i.e. a mapping ω:Aα→A
, where α
is an arbitrary cardinal number. A set with a system of algebraic operations defined on it is called a universal algebra.

Then I looked up Cartesian power of a set and found the following statement at Wikipedia.
A formal definition of the Cartesian product from set-theoretical principles follows from a definition of ordered pair. The most common definition of ordered pairs, Kuratowski's definition, is
(

,

) =
{
{

}
,
{

,

}
}
Under this definition,
(

,

)
is an element of

(

(

∪

)
)
, and

×

is a subset of that set, where

represents the power set operator. Therefore, the existence of the Cartesian product of any two sets in ZFC follows from the axioms of pairing, union, power set, and specification. Since functions are usually defined as a special case of relations, and relations are usually defined as subsets of the Cartesian product, the definition of the two-set Cartesian product is necessarily prior to most other definitions.
Why can constants be considered nullary operations?
It seems to me that to answer my question you have to explain why the mapping of the 0th Cartesian power of set A into A is a constant.

In free logic, constants can be non designating, meaning they don't have a referent.
From the SEP:

Free Logic
First published Mon Apr 5, 2010; substantive revision Fri Dec 11, 2020
Classical logic requires each singular term to denote an object in the domain of quantification—which is usually understood as the set of “existing” objects. Free logic does not. Free logic is therefore useful for analyzing discourse containing singular terms that either are or might be empty. A term is empty if it either has no referent or refers to an object outside the domain.


Likewise invalid is existential generalization: the principle that from a formula
A
containing a singular term
t
we may infer that there is something in
D
that satisfies
A
(
x
/
/
t
)
, the result of replacing one or more occurrences of
t
in
A
by
x
:


A
⊢
∃
x
A
(
x
/
/
t
)
,
If
t
does not denote an object in
D
then the truth of
A
does not guarantee that there exists in
D
an object that satisfies
A
(
x
/
/
t
)
. Though free logic rejects such classical inferences, it accepts no classically invalid inferences; hence it is strictly weaker than classical logic for a language with the same vocabulary.


To distinguish terms that denote members of
D
from those that do not, free logic often employs the one-place “existence” predicate, ‘
E
!
’ (sometimes written simply as ‘
E
’). For any singular term
t
,
E
!
t
is true if
t
denotes a member of
D
, false otherwise. ‘
E
!
’ may be either taken as primitive or (in bivalent free logic with identity) defined as follows:

E
!
t = df ∃x(x = t).

What this gentleman calls a singular term, is what I call a constant.
Definition
C is a non designating constant iff ~∃x[x=C]
Using set theory we must have
Definition
C is a designating constant iff ∃x[x=C].
This avoids the assumption that all constants denote exactly one thing.  The fewer assumptions the better.
In classical first order logic, all constants are specific constants.
Definition
C is a specific constant iff ∃!x[x=C]
When you write a ∈ A, both a, and A are specific constants.

Your definition of a constant doesn't make sense, as people have pointed out in comments and answers to your previous questions. Your confusion about constants as nullary operations is presumably a side effect of your misunderstanding of constants themselves. I'm voting to close this because I think it's not answerable as long as it's based on a nonsensical premise, and I think it won't be helpful to future readers.

@benrg, what you call a constant is what I call a specific constant.  Vote to close a good question, that you can't answer.

A nullary operation on A is a function A⁰ → A, that is 1 → A, that is an element of A.
There are many ways to see why A⁰ is a singleton set. You can see it in terms of functions: Aⁿ is the set of functions from a finite set with n elements to A, and there is exactly one function from the empty set to any set.
It should also be the case that A⁰ × Aⁿ ≃ A⁰⁺ⁿ ≃ Aⁿ, and this means that A⁰ should be a singleton.
Categorically speaking, Aⁿ is the limit of a diagram consisting of n copies of A, so A⁰ should be the limit of an empty diagram, i.e. a terminal object (i.e. a singleton set, in the category of sets).

Why is a singleton set a constant?

I didn't say that. A map out of a singleton set into A is an element of A. "Constant" doesn't really mean anything here.

I understand now why A⁰ is a singleton, but why are nullary operations constants?

I don't know what you mean by constant. Your definition is trivial: it holds for every C.

The symbol R for the Russell set does not denote.  It is a symbol that isn't a constant.  In a free logic, you can consider names that don't refer to anything like Jehovah God.  Thus my definition of constant is not trivial, it does not hold for R, or Jehovah, so it does not hold for every C.  If I want to refer to a symbol that denotes exactly one thing, I can.  I call such symbols specific constants.

It is trivial, in the sense that you can prove ∀C. ∃!x. x = C. If by "constant" you just mean a well-formed expression then that is a pretty strange use of the word, but also why would you doubt that an expression like λx.a : 1 → A is well-formed?

@you can't prove ∀C. ∃!x. x = C.   You left out possibilities.  C might not refer to anything, in which case  ∃C. ~∃!x. x = C, or C might refer to more than one thing, for example if C^2-1=0 then C=1 and C=-1.  Transitivity of equality isn't necessarily true.  Transitivity of equality is a special case of a more general law.

That is complete nonsense.

I said several things, what do you believe is nonsense?

change my statement to you can't prove ∀C. ∃!x. x = C. You left out possibilities. C might not refer to anything, in which case  ~∃!x. x = C, or C might refer to more than one thing, for example if C^2-1=0 then C=1 and C=-1.  Now it's not nonsense.

If C doesn't refer to anything, then ∃!x. x = C is not false, it's nonsense. We don't discuss nonsense in formal logic. The proof of the aforementioned statement is a simple application of the introduction rules for ∀ and ∃ and the reflexivity of equality. And transitivity of equality is necessarily true, at least in set theory and (most variants of) first-order logic. If you are discussing another logic, please clearly state so.

I'm using free logic, which is weaker than classical FOL, which deals with non designating constants.  C is a non designating constant iff ~∃x[x=C].  If ∃!x[x=C] then ∃x[x=C].  You have to know what the meaning of ∃x[x=C] is, to determine its truth value.  It means "there is at least one thing denoted by the symbol C.". That's clearly false when C is a non designating constant.
